# How do I make the dropdown menu not being down when you enter the website?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

When you enter my website (goerann.com) the dropdown register-box is down by default.

If I click in *Register*, the register-box toogles it visibility as I want, but it doesn't start hidden by default.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#signup').click(function() {
    $('.signupmenu').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

I want it to only show when you click on it. How can I make this happen?

Here's my jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/bdv2doxr/)

Comment: Try updating this html ine `<div class="signupmenu" style="display: none;">` I have changed style display from block to none. [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bdv2doxr/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using the `$(document).ready` event, you can hide the menu there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.signupmenu').hide();
  $('#signup').click(function() {
    $('.signupmenu').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

And here is [your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/bdv2doxr/2/).

Comment: Ah, perfekt Buzinas. Thank you so, so, much! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @GöranKempe If my answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes, both involving the removal of display: block. When you toggle this div, it will make the display block. Therefore, you can initialize it as display: none.

Change this:

```
<div class="signupmenu" style="display: block;">
```

to this:

```
<div class="signupmenu">
```

And also change this:

```
.signupmenu {
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    ...
```

to this:

```
.signupmenu {
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: none;
    ...
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bdv2doxr/3/)